# Mapping Play Framework form element to custom type

Tags: forms, scala, playframework, mapping

I would like to map form element to `java.sql.Time` the same way I am able to map `java.sql.Date`. I have the following piece of code:

```
  case class Item (timeField: java.sql.Time, dateField: java.sql.Date)
  val itemForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "timeField" -> sqlDate("H:mm"),
      "dateField" -> sqlDate("yyyy\M\d")
    )(Item.apply)(Item.unapply)
  )
```

Mapping do `dateField` works well, but is it possible to create custom mapping e.g. for time field? I'm expecting something like this

```
  val itemForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "timeField" -> sqlTime("H:mm"), //my own mapping function
      "dateField" -> sqlDate("yyyy\M\d")
    )(Item.apply)(Item.unapply)
  )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve this using a custom Formatter. The code would look something like this:

```
def sqlTime(pattern: String) = of(sqlTimeFormat(pattern))

def sqlTimeFormat(pattern: String): Formatter[java.sql.Time] = new Formatter[java.sql.Time] {
  def bind(key: String, data: Map[String, String]) = {
    try {
      val sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern)
      Right(new java.sql.Time(sdf.parse(data.getOrElse(key, "")).getTime))
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => Left(List(FormError(key, "Your error message")))
    }
  }
  def unbind(key: String, value: java.sql.Time) = Map(key -> value.formatted(pattern))
}
```

Note: I haven't tested this, you may have to make a few tweaks, but it should be close.